# how to filter XML

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm looking for filtering this xml [enter link description here](http://xml.weather.com/weather/local/FRXX0076?cc=%2aunit=m&hbhf=6&ut=C)
The best way to filter an xml it is :
-to run all the xml and to affect value in variable
-after that we rewrite this xml with this variable

is there any other method?
For this method i've used the dom like this:

```
    $flux= new DOMDocument();
if ($flux->load('http://xml.weather.com/weather/local/FRXX0076?unit=m&hbhf=6&ut=C'))  
{$loc=$flux->getElementsByTagName('t');
  foreach($loc as $lo)
    echo $lo->firstChild->nodeValue . "<br />";
}
```

in this code i've tried to display `<t>` but there are 2 balise `<t>` in `<hour>` , therefore i've two value of `<t>` instead the first child of `<hour>`

Comment: Am I mistaken, or you should go with $loc=$flux->getElementsByTagName('hour'), and then check the first t child inside? You can use an XPath to query the first "T" child of "hour" element. Also, there are several hour elements inside this document so I'm not exactly sure, what you want to output. For every hour, the "T" condition? Or what?

Comment: I want to output for every hour the T :)

Comment: How can i use Xpath in this case? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brief answer:

```
$flux= new DOMDocument();
if ($flux->load('http://xml.weather.com/weather/local/FRXX0076?unit=m&hbhf=6&ut=C'))  
{
    $xpath = new DomXPath($flux);

    $elements = $xpath->query("*/hour/t[1]");

    if (!is_null($elements)) {
      foreach ($elements as $element)
      {
        echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";

        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node)
        {
          echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I think you should know where to go from this point :)

More advanced version will be to issue XPath query on all hour elements ("*/hour") and then in foreach for each hour element issue another xpath query in this element context (`$xpath->query("*/t[1]", $hourElement);`). This way you'll also have access to hour object and can for example display this hour.

**UPDATE**

Simpler version of foreach:

```
if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element)
    {
        echo "<br/>".$element->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: waw, nice! it works for me, and i've learned a new and "professional" method :) thanks a lot Tomasz :)

Comment: No problem. It's woth mentioning, that simpleXML PHP extension also has XPath querying built in and is faster than DOM (as I think). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php